# How can I sort records in MySQL quickly?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-order-by

I have a database of 2,000,000+ records. I need to be able to sort by any of the 30 fields in the table quickly.

I tired adding an index(s) but it did not seem to increase the speed of the order by clause.

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblM` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fld1` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
`fld2` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
 ...
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `fld1` (`fld1`(1000)),
 KEY `fld2` (`fld2`(1000)),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21748375 ;
```

This is an example query I run:

```
SELECT id, fld1, fld2 FROM tblM ORDER BY fld2 ASC LIMIT 30
```

However this takes around 15 seconds to execute. Is there any way in which I can these types of queries execute in < 1 sec?

Sorting by primary key is only fast takes 0.0017 secs, it would be nice to have the other fields with the same performance. Disk space does not matter.

Comment: did you try forcing the index?

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think an index would matter if you're not applying a filter (`where` clause)
2. 2,000,000 rows with fields the size of `1024` is no small table, so some of this will come down to hardware
3. What is the speed if you run it again?  Perhaps caching will improve its performance.
4. Can you use InnoDB instead of MyISAM?

#### Edit

---

1. This article was written some time ago, so I'm not sure it still applies, but it was informative when it came out.  It discusses the difference between InnoDB and MyISAM, regarding clustered indexes. http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/04/how-to-exploit-mysql-index-optimizations/
2. Try using `USE INDEX` or `FORCE INDEX`:

   ```
    SELECT id, fld1, fld2 FROM tblM USE INDEX (fld2) ORDER BY fld2 ASC LIMIT 30
   ```

   or

   ```
    SELECT id, fld1, fld2 FROM tblM FORCE INDEX (fld2) ORDER BY fld2 ASC LIMIT 30
   ```

Comment: Thanks, very quick reply!
1. Yes, I noticed that if I specify a where condition then it is very quick to find the record (around 0.1036 sec). I thought it should MySQL being a large DMBS should be able to sort the data using an index by any column quickly as Excel does for millions of rows using PowerPivot.
2. Yes the database is around 1GB of data, when adding indexes for each field the size is 2GB of indexes = 3GB
3. Yes if I run it again it returns the data instantly being cached and all.

Comment: You need to look at the query plan, to see if it's it's doing a full table scan.

Comment: Yes it is doing a full table scan for records. Any idea why it is doing it? I thought the data would already be sorted with the index? *confused*

Comment: That's one of the problems with MyISAM, try forcing the index as per my second edit, or using InnoDB, which clusters/sorts by index.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an index in the right order that includes all the fields you're selecting.  So for your query:

```
SELECT id, fld1, fld2 FROM tblM ORDER BY fld2 ASC LIMIT 30
```

You could create this index:

```
create index ix_tblM_fld2 on tblM (fld2, fld1, id)
```

One word of advice re this:

> Sorting by primary key is only fast
>   takes 0.0017 secs, it would be nice to
>   have the other fields with the same
>   performance. Disk space does not
>   matter.

In order for the database to work with your data, it has to be loaded into memory.  Loading into memory is a slow operation, and RAM is generally not unlimited.  Creating too many indexes can significantly burden a server.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must create index for those fields,it will reduce your query time.

Comment: `I tired adding an index(s) but it did not seem to increase the speed of the order by clause.`

Comment: Yes correct, I did
ALTER TABLE `tblM` ADD INDEX ( `fld1` );
ALTER TABLE `tblM` ADD INDEX ( `fld2` );
... 
ALTER TABLE `tblM` ADD INDEX ( `fldN` );
This doesn't speed up the time on the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Just a note, adding an index to all your fields will most likely slow down your query as it will increase the index scan

Answer (score 0):

Try changing engine from MYISAM to INNODB.

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to sort on a 1024 length varchar? that's a lot of potential work to do...

can you get away with perhaps sorting for the first 10 characters? I haven't tested this in MySQL, but if you created a `fld1_short` field that was varchar(10) and populate it with the first 10 characters of `fld1`, **and** create an index on it, it might give better performance.

You might want to read up on the [MySQL doco](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) regarding `ORDER BY` optimisation - you could well be hitting your `sort_buffer_size` and/or `read_rnd_buffer_size` settings, given the amount of data you're working with.